# How to Cancel one job as per month in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to Cancel a one job as per month in javascript.when i click on cancel button i want to get the popup also mention with message "you cancel 1 job as per month  and yes or no" please help me.. i am very stuck in that code.

Comment: Please add more context and most importantly your code! What problem do you have specifically? What is that job you are referring to? There are so many things missing from your question

Comment: No one here can help you without any code. Show how ur code looks like. What you want to do. What have you tried and what is problem

Comment: i am trying to implementing code but can't still not in process so i am unable to send that code.. so please send one of sample code. on click on cancel button..@MaheerAli and @Patrick Hollweck

Comment: As much as we would like to help you we cant. The way you formulate your question is very vague. Your English is broken at best and you still haven't answered what you mean with "Job". What is a job? Do you want to cancel the click of the button?

Comment: we have two user one user can post job and one user accept job. both can cancel the posted job as per month.. we have use there one cancel button so i am trying to finding solution but still can't find out.@Patrick Hollweck. Thans in advance. And "Job" like  (cooking, plumbing, yard cleaning).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a database or not, but to get things going you need to attach a change or click event on the checkbox. An example of a change event is below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
  let checkboxEl = document.getElementsByName("theJob")[0]; // a lot of different ways to select the dom element
  let spanEl = document.querySelector(".js_strikeThrough");
  let checkAttr = checkboxEl.getAttribute('data-cancel');
  checkboxEl.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if(checkAttr) {
      checkAttr = !checkAttr;
      spanEl.classList.add("strikeThrough");
    } else {
      spanEl.classList.remove("strikeThrough");
      checkAttr = !checkAttr;
    }
  }, false);

}, false);
```

```css
.strikeThrough{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<form> 
  <input type="checkbox" data-cancel="false" name="theJob" value="Clean"><span class="js_strikeThrough">Wash Car</span>
</form>
```

Where the checkAttr value is being changed in the above snippet, is where you would need to call your database methods to update the value in the database and add popup messages. Not sure what db you are using.